# How to use ElasticSearch geo_distance on ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, geolocation

**Hits**

```
{
    "_index" : "users",
    "_type" : "user",
    "_id" : "001",
    "_score" : 1,
    "_source" : {
      "utype" : "user",
      "username" : "test",
      "location" : {
          "lat" : 0.1,
          "lon" : 0.0
      },
      "uid" : "001"
    }
}
```

**Node.js - app.js**

```
client.search({
    index: 'users',
    type: 'user',
    body: {
        query: {
            filtered: {
                query: {
                    match_all: {}
                },
                filter: {
                    geo_distance: {
                        distance: '2km',
                        location: {
                            lat: 0.0,
                            lon: 0.1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    var hits = response.hits.hits;
    console.log(hits);
}, function (error, response) {
    // ...
});
```

**Error**

> *"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures*

... I'm not sure if i'm using the **geo_distance** correctly but i did use the same format used at **elasticsearch** documentation. I'm using ExpressJS installed elasticsearch npm and used the client.search code above for geo_distance filtering. And also the hits returns not just one object. Can anyone help me how to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the first query and replace "location" by "user.location" because ElasticSearch interprete it like a type not like a attribute.

```
 client.search({
    index: 'users',
    body: {
          filter: {
              geo_distance: {
                   distance: '2km',
                   location: {
                       lat: 0.0,
                       lon: 0.1
                   }
              }
         }
   }               
}).then(function (response) {
    var hits = response.hits.hits;
    console.log(hits);
}, function (error, response) {
    // ...
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: "user" is the type right? nope still search failed.

Comment: try removing the first query and if it not works try with this ` filter: {
            geo_distance: {
                distance: '2km',
                user.location: {
                    lat: 0.0,
                    lon: 0.1
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: still got this error **nested: QueryParsingException[[users] failed to find geo_point field [user.location]];**